# deserialize json array to list wp7

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7

i need to get data from sub-array inside json,but its not getting converted into list, below is my json string

{"responseCode":"0","responseObject":{"TotalRecords":25,"TotalDisplayRecords":25,"aaData":[{"InvoiceId":16573,"somedata..},"  appCrmAccount(some title,total 100 such titles)
amount":40086.00,"invoiceNumber":"12,accountName":"dfgAsfsadf"," dueDateStr":"04/24/2012"(data to be get into list)

here is my code:

```
var djson = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(dataList));
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
dataList result = (dataList)djson.ReadObject(stream);//not getting execute
```

kindly help..
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean not getting execute? an error? exception?

Comment: Could you post code of class "dataList" here? Do you using DataContract and DataMember attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what exactly you need to do is take array element return as a DataContract and its sub member as DataMember  as

```
[DataContract] 
public class mainresponse
 {
 [DataMember]
 public resultmap arrayelement { get; set; }
 }  
 [DataContract]
 public class resultmap 
{
 [DataMember] 
 public string substringhere { get; set; } 
 }     
 var djson = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Mainresponse));
 var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responsestring));
 mainresponse result = (mainresponse)djson.ReadObject(stream);
```

that it...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(proxy_DownloadStringCompleted);
    proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(""));
}
```

And need to parse the returned JSON as below. In parameter to create instance of DataContractJsonSrrializer we are passing List of Student.

```
void proxy_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));

    DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Student>));
    List<Student> result = obj.ReadObject(stream) as List<Student>;
    lstStudents.ItemsSource = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mark all classes and properties DataContract and DataMember attributes. Using you code snippet i created something like this:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Result
    {
        [DataMember(Name="responseCode")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="responseObject")]
        public ResponseObject Result { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int TotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="aaData")]
        public DataItem[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DataItem
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "InvoiceId")]
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

        // Others properties
    }
```

Comment: Mark it as answer, pls, if it is.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but this is not working for arrays... though I don't understand what is this: Name="aaData"?

Comment: Name="aaData" is just property for attribute that indicate name of field in source. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx