# Get and display json data in windows phone

Tags: c#, json, listview, windows-phone

I have developed many apps for iOS, now i want to learn Windows phone development.

In windows phone i want to display data in my listView

`I want to display this json data in my ListView,`

```
      {
        "Event_Id":2673,
        "Event_Name":"Bruno Mars",
        "Event_Navigateurl":"bruno-mars",
        "IphoneImage":"http://mywebsite/images/6349764112819brunomars_34628_1_1_20130227170016.jpg",
        "Price":38.5,
        "SubCategory":"Rock and Pop",
        "SubCategoryURL":"rock-and-pop",
      },
     {

        "Event_Id":752,
        "Event_Name":"One Direction",
        "Event_Navigateurl":"one-direction",
        "IphoneImage":"http://mywebsite/images/634848503231825onedirection_34537_1_1_20110926162229.jpg",
        "Price":10,
        "SubCategory":"Rock and Pop",
        "SubCategoryURL":"rock-and-pop",
    },
   {
       . . . 
   }
```

Can any one suggest, how to display this json data from URL.

Please help i am new in Windows phone.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: have a look  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309643/deserialize-json-array-to-list-wp7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please refer my Question.
i had same query to bind the json data in listbox.
so, Please refer this link.

> [How to bind Json data in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781509/how-to-bind-json-in-list-box-in-windows-phone-7)

I hope you get the Solution of your query.

And for getting the json data from url. for that refer this code.

```
Public MyJson()
{
   String myUrl = "Your WebService URL";
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(myUrl), UriKind.Relative);
   wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
}

private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   var myData = e.Result;
   // You will get you Json Data here..
}
```

And finally you will get your Json Data Easily.